# String to integers

Tags: java, string, integer

how can I convert IPv4 to four several integers.?
Here is some example:

This is an input:
158.195.16.154

And I want output like this:

int a=158;

int b=195;

int c=16;

int d=154;

Thx for the answers.

Comment: Is this a Microsoft placement question?

Answer (score 0):

```
String ip = "158.195.16.154";
String[] tokens = ip.split("\\.");
int[] numbers = new int[tokens.lenght];
for (int i = 0; i<tokens.lenght; i++) numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String Ip = "158.195.16.154";
String[] arr = Ip.split("\\.");
int[] intIp = new int[4];
int i=0;

for(String s:arr){
    intIp[i] = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```